# Linksys E1550 Wifi Dropped Packets?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt

I have a Linksys E1550 router that consistently drops packets (tested using ping to the gateway address) over wifi, even when my PC is sitting DIRECTLY next to the router.

I ran the ping overnight and this morning, and got the results below:

```
Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 44313, Received = 41447, Lost = 2866 (6% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1195ms, Average = 7ms
```

I have installed DD-WRT in an attempt to resolve this issue, but I still get dropped packets.  I have tried manually setting the channel to a channel that isn't used as much in my area (detected using Wifi Analyzer android App).

This occurs on multiple pcs and laptop computers, so it isn't an issue with my NIC.  I typically get one or two ping timeouts every minute, enough that games like Hearthstone consistently drops me, and my work VPN has trouble staying connected.  The ping time jumps from 1 ms to 100 ms pretty regularly.

Are there any settings that I can adjust to increase the performance of my router?  Could this be a noise issue?

Comment: Are you sure it is the router and not something with your ISP and/or modem? What if you connect directly to the modem with you computer and run the ping overnight, do you still get dropped packets? Not sure how feasible testing a different router would be, but that's another option.

Comment: I am pinging my router's gateway, and I have tested with the WAN cable disconnected.  When plugged into the router via an ethernet cable, I get no dropped packets and <1ms ping times consistently.

Comment: Do you have any other devices like bluetooth ... that use 2.4Ghz?  Antenna alignment might help:  "This is because radio reception is maximized when both client and access point have matched polarization (antennas pointing along the same plane)."  http://lifehacker.com/the-best-way-to-point-your-wi-fi-router-antennas-perpe-1605924745

Comment: Right, I mis-read your post.  Sorry about that one.  Are there a lot of wireless AP's around you?  I know you switched channels to a less busy one.  Seems like something with the wireless portion, seems like some sort of noise issue or interference.  I see according to specs it's only 2.4 GHz band, so my next suggestion of trying 5 GHz wouldn't work obviously.

Comment: I have bluetooth turned on my phone, and a bluetooth headset, but it wasn't in use at the time of this test.

Comment: @StackAbstraction Also, this router doesn't have an external antenna.  It's internal to the device, so how should I orient my router?

Comment: Looked up a picture, with the lowest potential energy i.e. the largest side horizontal.  Notebook with Screen vertical and several feet away direct line of sight and same vertical height.  Thinking, Interference or defect with router.  You could take the (router/notebook) to a spot with a car ac adapter for testing away from wifi noise.